# What's the difference between hard-boiled fiction and crime fiction?

Tags: terminology

I'm seriously confused now. I just read (in Wikipedia) that detective fiction is a sub-genre of both crime fiction and mystery. Now there's this hard-boiled thing. Those money-grubbing editors and critics only do this to annoy, I think.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crime fiction covers a broad range of writing about crime and the people involved in criminal activity -- the police, private detectives, criminals, lawyers, and so on.  The plots range from  the solving of the mystery of who committed the crime (a so-called "whodunit"), to following the police in their activities (a police procedural), to the semi-humorous antics of ordinary citizens and amateur detectives (the "cozy").

The hard-boiled genre are gritty stories of the criminal underworld, usually containing sex, violence, and corruption (both public and private).  The famous authors of the genre -- Hammett and Chandler -- wrote from the point of view of a protagonist who was a lone private detective, tough but honest and determined to unravel the mystery of a murder in the face of deceitful women and uncooperative clients.

People who study this kind of thing differentiate hard-boiled from *noir* by noting that the former describes style and the latter, content.  *Noir* is dark and grim, no matter its style.  Hard-boiled is gritty and unsentimental, no matter its outlook.  Details in a discussion [here](http://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/890414-hard-boiled-vs-noir).  There are numerous works where the two overlap, and it's certainly possible to have a story that's hardboiled or grim or both but that doesn't involve crime, but the terms are usually associated with crime fiction.

Why *hard boiled*?  Perhaps it was the attraction of "hard" meaning tough and "boiled" meaning inured to heat.  Perhaps it was metaphoric from the tough exterior of a hard-boiled egg.  In any case, this was a popular term in the 1920s to describe people from [purchasing agents](https://books.google.com/books?id=oN8gAQAAMAAJ&q=%22hard%20boiled%22&dq=%22hard%20boiled%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiErY6VjrnJAhWJyj4KHRGRDrA4FBDoAQhBMAY) to [sled dogs](https://books.google.com/books?id=sBhVyLt8DMUC&pg=PA19&dq=%22hard%20boiled%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigjuLDjrnJAhWIbj4KHb-PB8w4KBDoAQgqMAE#v=onepage&q=%22hard%20boiled%22&f=false).  And it gave rise to this illustrative pun from [*Colliers Illustrated Weekly*](https://books.google.com/books?id=A-McAQAAMAAJ&q=%22hard%20boiled%22&dq=%22hard%20boiled%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj77oevirnJAhUCUz4KHfTUALc4HhDoAQgsMAI) from 1926:

> Pancho Villa, champion of all the **hard-boiled** yeggs<sup>*</sup>, wasn't in on
>   this, but his brother Hipolito got Bud and his friends safely over the
>   border.

In the same year archetypical hard-boiled author Ernest Hemingway used the term in *The Sun Also Rises*:

> “It is awfully easy to be **hard-boiled** about everything in the daytime,
>   but at night it is another thing.”

It's possible that the term arose from the [invention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_hat) of the E.D. Bullard Company, was a mining equipment manufacturer, which in 1919 patented a precursor to the modern hard hat, a  "hard-boiled hat" made of steamed canvas, glue and black paint.

*Noir* is no mystery (so to speak); it's French for black.

* A *yegg* is underworld cant for a thief or burglar, especially a safecracker.

Comment: But why is it called *hard-boiled*, what's gritty, dark and subversive about *hard-boiled*? I think of a hard-boiled sweet, or hard-boiled eggs. Is *hard* therefore synonymous with *tough*, and not easily chewable?

Comment: @Mari-LouA "Dark" is more appropriate for *noir*, and I don't know about subversive.  I've added some history of the term in the answer.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I thought of subversive because of  the description of hard-boiled fiction, i.e. sex and violence, it sounded anti-conventional. Nice edit by the way!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Far be it from me to advise you on how to perceive sex and violence, but in the crime fiction under discussion -- say, Chandler's *Murder, My Sweet* aka *Farewell, My Lovely* -- sex, violence, and their mix is the conventional and expected.  Just beneathe a veneer of hypocrisy, of course.